# How can I set the access right to 'l' for every directory in a path (in an Andrew File System)?

Tags: symlink, afs

I saved a java program (demo.java) in a university's linux server inside of a directory called "Codes". The Codes directory itself is in the Desktop folder. So the path of the java program is Home/Bob/Desktop/Codes/demo.java

Now in order for the university to access the demo.java file, I'm apparently supposed to have ‘l‘ access rights set in every directory from my home directory all the way down to the directory where my program/code resides (which is Codes). So the Home directory, the Desktop directory and the Codes directory need to have the 'l' access right.

Now unfortunately, I haven't found a lot of online tutorials for AFS, so I'm kinda in the dark here.

Comment: `l` access right? As in `lrw...`? That means the file is a link. It would be best if you quote whatever instructions you got, as is, in the question.

Comment: @muru  "The code should be made available in a directory in the distributed AFS file system on the servers for the users jonny and / or jon. For us to be able to access your code, we need to have ‘l‘ (list) access rights set in every directory from your home directory all the way down to the directory where your program/code resides. For the directory where the code is, we need to have ‘rl’ (read + list) access rights. You use the fs command to set access rights (make sure you use the proper fs command – there may be several different commands with the same name)."

Comment: Oh, that's `x` in normal Unix permission systems. AFS is different. Please edit that in to the question and mention you are using the Andrew File System.

Comment: Right...now I have no experience in AFS. So how exactly can I change the access right of all the directories (bob, Desktop and Codes) to 'l'?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
fs setacl directory user/group rights
```

(This command gives a certain right to a certain group of the indicated directory)